# Creating a grayscale image in a python byte array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

I need to pass a grayscale image as binary array to a DLL in python. I am using PIL to load the original image, converting it to a grayscale, and they copying the pixels to the c_char array. My code looks like this:

```
from ctypes import *
from PIL import Image

grayScale = Image.open(fileName).convert('L')
pixelMap = grayScale.load() #create the pixel map

pixel_array = c_char * (grayScale.height * grayScale.width)
pixels = pixel_array()

for y in range(grayScale.height):
    i = y * grayScale.width
    for x in range(grayScale.width): 
        pixels[i+x] = pixelMap[x,y]
```

'pixels' is then passed as a c_char_p parameter to the DLL that needs it.

This works, but is quite slow with even modest sized images. Not being familiar with PIL (or Python for that matter), is there a more efficient way to access the grayscale data than pixel by pixel?

Comment: Why have you removed all your `import` statements that show which modules you are using? Why haven't you shared your image? Where's the definition of `c_char`? Thank you.

Comment: This is just a snippet of an otherwise much larger program; I've included the relevant imports (c_char comes from ctypes, the interface types for legacy DLL's). The actual image is moot (opening the image and generating the pixel map works just fine)--I looking for a more efficient way to access the pixel data to copy it the c_char arrary--the type I have to use to pass the image data the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I've found the solution:

```
from ctypes import *
from PIL import Image

grayScale = Image.open(fileName).convert('L')
pixels = grayScale.tobytes()
```

The .tobytes() function returns a Bytes object, which is compatible with a c_char (when passed as a parameter to the DLL, a pointer is used, or c_char_p, which works with a Bytes object).

Note this is an immutable type, which for my use case was fine (the DLL does not modify the pixels data).